# Having issues in adding multiple js files in my wordpress plugin

Tags: jquery, wordpress

```
function add_scripts()
{

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
    wp_register_script('pr_cycle_all',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'/js/dom.jsPlumb-1.js');
    wp_register_script('pr_slider',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'/js/jquery.jsPlumb-1.js');
    wp_register_script('pr_validation_engine',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'/js/jquery-2.1.js');
    wp_register_script('pr_validation_locale',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'/js/jquery-ui.js');

    wp_register_style('problem solver',plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) .'/styles/style.css');

    wp_enqueue_script('pr_cycle_all');
    wp_enqueue_script('pr_validation_engine');
    wp_enqueue_script('pr_slider');
    wp_enqueue_script('pr_validation_locale');


    wp_enqueue_style('problem solver');

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'add_scripts' );
```

Comment: What is the issue, be specific

Answer (score 0):

The code seems to be fine, shouldn't be any problem with it. I dont know how you are calling this file though, , it might be stupid but you can try plugins_url instead of plugin_dir_url.

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'problem_solver', plugins_url( '/styles/style.css' , dirname(__FILE__) ), false );
```

And what about the space you have in the handler?